# correct way to start/stop postgres database pg_ctl or service postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know correct way of starting/stopping postgres database.
There are two ways

1. `pg_ctl start/stop`
2. `service postgresql start/stop`

I would like to know how they are different from each other, which one should I use? Are there any pros/cons?

Comment: look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490425/what-is-the-difference-between-service-postgresql-start-and-pg-ctl-start

Answer (score 29):

#### If you are using Mac with brew

To start:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

To stop:

```
brew services stop postgresql
```

#### Using pg_ctl

To start:

```
pg_ctl start -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

To stop:

```
pg_ctl stop -D /usr/local/var/postgres -m smart
```

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: `brew start services` and `brew stop services` are NOT built into brew.  Those are extras - part of the homebrew/services tap.  See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services

Comment: It should be `brew services stop` as stated in docs https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services

Answer (score 7):

If you view `/etc/init.d/postgres${VER}` file, you will find out, that when you run `service postgresql start/stop` it runs `pg_ctl $OPTIONS start/stop`. The only difference is that service gives you handy way to store environmental variables and enable/disable autostart.

All above can be done manually, using `pg_ctl` and some scripting.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux I do the following

to start:

```
systemctl start postgresql
```

to stop:

```
systemctl stop postgresql
```

Answer (score 3):

On macOS, I've found that running the following will stop and start the server

- `cd /` to avoid permission errors, e.g. `could not identify current directory: Permission denied`
- Start: `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/15/data start`
- Stop: `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/15/data stop`
- Remember to update `15` to the real path of your Postgres.

Comment: This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /datadir

pg_ctl -D $(pwd) stop

pg_ctl -D $(pwd) start

#pg_ctl needs the path of the data (-D)
```

Can be directly used:

```
pg_ctl -D /mnt/raid/pdb stop

pg_ctl -D /mnt/raid/pdb stop
```

[Ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pg-ctl.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Commands do work on postgres10

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is: you should stop it how you started it.

The `service` command is used to control System V services, so if you control PostgreSQL via a System V service (for example to auto (re)start the PostgreSQL daemon), then you should stop/start it with the `service` command.

The `pg_ctl` command is a native PostgreSQL command to control the server. You specify the server by passing the location of the data directory the server is running from. Under the hood, the `pg_ctl` command obtains the PID of the server process via the PID file in the data directory and then sends the appropriate signals to the process ([source, search for SHUTDOWN_MODE](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_ctl/pg_ctl.c)):

```
 pg_ctl stop -m s[mart]     --> SIGTERM
 pg_ctl stop -m f[ast]      --> SIGINT
 pg_ctl stop -m i[mmediate] --> SIGQUIT
```

So, if for whatever reason pg_ctl is not working (PID file not obtainable), you can just send the appropriate signal to the PostgreSQL server process.