# Postgres is hogging port 3000 and I can't kill it

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, macos, terminal

I keep getting "Something is already running on port 3000", and I've tried `sudo lsof -i :3000`, and I get this:

```
postgres 92237 postgres    7u  IPv6 0xcbfedaba1d3eb2b7      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
postgres 92237 postgres    8u  IPv4 0xcbfedaba2d4680c7      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

So I ran  `sudo kill -9 92237` to stop it

But more instances of postgres will generate after I kill it, how can I stop this??

Comment: I've already stopped postgres with brew

Comment: I use `ps -ef | grep postgres`

Comment: will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45671327/4440387

Comment: The default port for Postgres is 5432. Are you sure this is actually Postgres running, not something like Ruby on Rails? What program is giving the error message: "Something is already running on port 3000" ?